# Програмное влючение передачи данных на android

Tags: android, android-studio

Всем привет!)

Есть две кнопки: btn_on и  btn_off

По нажатию первой должна включаться передача данных (мобильный интернет, не wifi), а по нажатию второй - выключаться.

Подскажите, как сделать, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй вот это http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread1396541.html
возможно поможет

Comment: там среди параметров ф-и есть context, я не понимаю, как его передать в функцию правильно

Comment: ну знаю как у тебя работает приложение но логика вроде должна была бы быть такая:
При каком то действии (пользователь нажал какуюто кнопку, или загрузилась активити) вызывается тот метод setMobileDataEnabled(...).

По поводу Context, возможно ты не понимаешь как его извлечь и Activity?

есть ключевое слово this

Comment: ключевое слово this (синтаксис Java) которое возвращает ссылку на текущий Объект (то есть на самого себя)

выглядеть будет так setMobileDataEnabled(this, enabled);